# Problem with the structure of Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I don't know what's happening there but there some serious issue with the following code :

```
model=Sequential([])
block1

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation="relu",input_shape=(64,64,3)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))

block2

model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5),activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Conv2D(32,(5,5),activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(2,2))



block3
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(256,activation="relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(3,activation="softmax"))
```

As soon as I call the training phase, it stops in between and doesn't proceed it literally froze during 2 or 3rd epoch.

I thought there's a problem with my system's memory but its not.

1. If I remove batch normalisation from 3rd block code works.
2. If I add block2 again, means 3 CNN blocks and then dense block code works.
3. If I remove block 2 completely code works.

What's exactly going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. The problem may be with GPU memory. Check your GPU memory usage during training using nvidia-smi command.

Comment: GPU memory utilisation is 50%, 50% is remaining. I tried the more denser network (as mentioned in 2) it worked completely fine.